# Cannot align items to the right side in bootstrap

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

```
    <div id="page-content-wrapper">
      <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light" id="">
        <button class="navbar-toggler" id="menu-toggle"><span class="material-icons iconColor">notes</span></button>
        <div class="row">
          <div class="input-group col-8 searchBarMain">
              <input class="form-control py-2 border-right-0 border" placeholder="Type to search" id="example-search-input">
              <span class="input-group-append">
                  <button class="btn btn-outline-secondary border-left-0 border" type="button">
                      <i class="fa fa-search"></i>
                  </button>
                </span>
          </div>
          <div class="col-4 user-info float-right">
            <span>Firstname Lastname</span>
            <span class="material-icons iconColor">account_circle</span>
          </div>
      </div>
      </nav>
  </div>
```

I am trying to align items to the far right side of the screen. The problem is that the items stay in the middle of the screen although I'm using the 12 column layout and the `far-right` class. Thank you in advance.

Comment: use the `float-right` as it is here https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/utilities/float/  instead of `far-right`.

Comment: I tried using it and it puts the elements right next to the other.

Answer (score 0):

A rule with BS is use its template and if alter must be mini-mini-mimimum. Dont put grid layout to control appearance of BS navbar. For all nav-item to right use class "ml-auto" if use BS4, use class "me-auto" if use BS5

You a bit tumbled up BS navbar code, so I provide a working clean code below, you just need to cut and paste your elements into this framework. You may see that I apply mr-auto  move logo to most left, and ml-auto to

to move all nav links to the right

If this answer works for you, please green tick to accept as final answer

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-dark navbar-expand-sm fixed-top">
        <div class="container">
            <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#Navbar">
                <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
            </button>
           <a class="navbar-brand mr-auto" href="./index.html"> <img src="#" height="50" width="50"> </a> 
           <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="Navbar">
               <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto">
                    <li class="navbar-item active"><a class="nav-link" href="./index.html"> Home</a></li>
                    <li class="navbar-item"><a class="nav-link" href="./aboutus.html">About</a></li>
                    <li class="navbar-item"><a class="nav-link" href="#">Menu</a></li>
                    <li class="navbar-item"><a class="nav-link" href="./contactus.html"> Contact</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>         
    </nav>
```